# Run Vault server configuration in Docker Compose, commands are blocked

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hashicorp-vault

I need to run a Vault container https://hub.docker.com/_/vault with all the configuration setup when it finished.

That means I need to execute this commands AFTER the server started:

```
vault secrets enable -path clickhouse/kv kv-v2 
vault secrets enable -path clickhouse/transit transit
```

The problem is that if I add the commands in docker-compose.yaml they are never executed.
I even tried to add echo to check what was blocking.

```
environment:
  - VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
  - VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=devsecret
  - VAULT_TOKEN=devsecret
  - VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8200
cap_add:
  - IPC_LOCK
command: 
  - /bin/sh 
  - -c
  - | 
    echo "Test!!!"
    echo "Test???"
    vault server -dev
    echo "Test***"
    vault secrets enable -path clickhouse/kv kv-v2 
    vault secrets enable -path clickhouse/transit transit
```

Everything after `vault server -dev` isn't executed.

I tried to fork and add & ; or && to keep the sever from blocking.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, vault docker starts with `vault server -dev`. Refer the [link](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/vault/latest/images/sha256-3d755c241fe485806ce593a3d356ef34f9035378d5e48b1aed271f416c98c6f9?context=explore).

So, you can pretty much use that docker image as your base and then build a new docker with the other `vault` commands in `RUN` layers.